# Variable app loading time using AsyncTask

Tags: android, time, bitmap, loading, android-asynctask

I'm writing an Android game which uses an AsyncTask when the app starts to scale graphics and cut spritesheets into arrays of Bitmaps.

The problem is that the loading time at the start of the app does not seem to be consistant. When testing on my phone (HTC MyTouch/Magic) the loading time when I first launch the app after install is often around 0.5 seconds but sometimes takes up to around 2 seconds.

Is there any reason why this might be the case or is it unavoidable? Each time I've run the app it's been under the same conditions, with no additional programs running in the background etc.

I can add the AsyncTask code if that might help.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I've seen much larger discrepancies in loading times from an app I wrote along with some downloaded apps.  I can only attribute that to the OS itself and the processing it is doing at the time of app start.  I'm sure there are possibilities of your own code causing issues depending on what it is doing, most especially if it is talking with a server.

Comment: You might want to watch this: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=c4znvD-7VDA

Comment: Cheers for these comments. The video definitely seems useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason why this might be the case or is it unavoidable?

There are a few possible reasons why this might be the case, and they are unavoidable. Here are two that pop to mind:

- While you may think there are "no additional programs running in the background", the operating system may disagree with you
- If you are reading data from flash storage, access times may be variable due to the peculiarities of YAFFS2 (e.g., global lock for an entire partition)

Also, do not forget that device CPU and flash speeds will vary themselves. While your device is, um, on the slow end, there may be some that are slower still, and there will be many that are faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess most devices have a 1GHz processor these days so the time taken on my phone should pretty much be an upper bound. I'll play around with it some more to see if I can save a bit more time when loading.